# How would I monitor Pokemon Go's Http requests?

Tags: android, http, reverse-engineering

I would love to see what requests Pokemon Go makes and what the responses look like, similar to using chrome dev tools on a website. Is there any way I can monitor an android app's requests the same way I would monitor a website's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others have already mentioned the good MITM proxy tools for this -- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/), [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html), and [MITM Proxy](https://mitmproxy.org/). However, Pokemon Go uses [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for communication, not XML, JSON, etc. This format is harder for a human to work with, as it does not show the data with human-readable keys or values. Without the original schema .proto files that the app and server use to interpret the data, you'll have to look at the raw data and try to make sense of it by doing different requests and seeing how the data changes to try to understand what different fields might represent. You can then construct .proto files yourself so the data can be displayed in a human-readable way.

Answer (score 5):

This is the path I try some times (not specifically to Pokemon, though):

1. Install mitmproxy in you computer: https://mitmproxy.org/
2. Start the proxy in some port: `mitmproxy -p 3128`
3. In your device network settings, configure it to use a proxy, and with manual settings add the IP of your computer and the port you started the proxy server (e.g. 3128) - assuming your device and computer are in the same wifi network.
4. Use the app you want to inspect requests
5. HTTP requests will show up in the mitmproxy interface

Comment: Addendum: You may need to visit the magic website "mitm.it" after enabling mitmproxy to view HTTPS-encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 2):

These answers were all perfectly correct at the time, but I feel like some additional information is warranted given some changes. In version 0.31, Pokemon Go added certificate pinning, which prevents basic MITM proxying to work without doing one of two things to unpin the certificate.

1. You can attempt to find a Pokemon GO APK that has had certificate pinning removed, then perform MITM proxying as usual
2. You can use an xposed module such as http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.rastapasta.android.xposed.pokemongo to trick

In addition, the protobuf files have been fairly successfully decoded as of this time, with projects such as [this one](https://github.com/rastapasta/pokemon-go-mitm) helping to make life considerably easier to sniff on traffic such as this.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make all requests from your device go through your PC and list them. If you use Windows I advise http://www.telerik.com/fiddler, for Mac and Linux https://www.charlesproxy.com/.